# Excel VBA Subscript out of range when reading tracking 10

Tags: vba, excel

I have a Master excel file called "PEDIDOS 2017_V3.xlsx" and another excel called "Tracking", containing this code. "Tracking" excel file open the master file "Pedidos...", search lines and columns for specific information and paste the information in the "Tracking file". Everything works except tracking 10:

```
'-------Tracking10
    pedidosT.Activate
    Application.CutCopyMode = False
    If IsEmpty(Worksheets("TRACK").Range("CP" & x)) Then
        If Worksheets("TRACK").Range("U" & x).Value <> vbNullString Then
            If Worksheets("TRACK").Range("CL" & x).Value <> vbNullString Then
                If Worksheets("TRACK").Range("CM" & x).Value <> vbNullString Then
                    If Worksheets("TRACK").Range("CN" & x).Value <> vbNullString Then

        Set JuntaCampos = Union(Worksheets("TRACK").Range("U" & x), Worksheets("TRACK").Range("CL" & x), Worksheets("TRACK").Range("CM" & x), Worksheets("TRACK").Range("CN" & x), Worksheets("TRACK").Range("CO" & x), Worksheets("TRACK").Range("CR" & x))
        JuntaCampos.Copy

        myTargetName.Activate
        Worksheets("TRACKING_HERMES").Select
        Worksheets("TRACKING_HERMES").Range("A" & y).Select
        ActiveCell.PasteSpecial xlPasteValues
        Worksheets("TRACKING_HERMES").Range("D" & y) = Left(Worksheets("TRACKING_HERMES").Range("D" & y), 49)
        Worksheets("TRACKING_HERMES").Range("E" & y) = Left(Worksheets("TRACKING_HERMES").Range("E" & y), 39)
        Worksheets("TRACKING_HERMES").Range("I" & y) = Format(Now, "yyyy-mm-dd HH:mm:ss.000")
        Worksheets("TRACKING_HERMES").Range("Q" & y) = "10"
        Worksheets("TRACKING_HERMES").Range("R" & y) = x
        y = y + 1

                    End If
                End If
            End If
        End If
    End If
```

As you will see, the code is exactly like the other tracking codes, except the cell ranges to be copied.
Whenever i have a tracking 10, it copies and paste the values, just like the other trackings but it stops giving an error "Subscript out of range".

Here's the all code:

```
                Public Sub Validar_Tracking()

            Dim Final As Long
            Dim y As Integer
            Dim JuntaCampos As Range
            Dim Starting As Integer

            'In Tracking i put the number of the line where i want to start (M1)    
            Starting = Worksheets("TRACKING_HERMES").Range("M1")

            Application.ScreenUpdating = False

            'clean beforee start
            Worksheets("TRACKING_HERMES").Range("A2:I3000").ClearContents
            Worksheets("TRACKING_HERMES").Range("K2:R3000").ClearContents

            'target (Sheet Tracking)
            Set myTargetName = ActiveWorkbook

            'source (wbk Pedidos)
            myFileName = "PEDIDOS 2017_V3.xlsx"
            stPath = ThisWorkbook.Path
            stFullName = stPath & "\" & myFileName
            Set myWorkbook = Workbooks.Open(stFullName)
            Set pedidosT = ActiveWorkbook


            '----------------------------------------------------------------------------
                y = 2

               ' find lines in pedidos_sheet tracking
                pedidosT.Activate
                With Worksheets("TRACK")
                    Final = .Cells(.Rows.Count, "U").End(xlUp).Row
                End With

                'Loop start
                For x = Starting To Final

                'search on each line

            '-------Tracking1
                    If IsEmpty(Worksheets("TRACK").Range("AN" & x)) Then
                        If Worksheets("TRACK").Range("U" & x).Value <> vbNullString Then
                            If Worksheets("TRACK").Range("AJ" & x).Value <> vbNullString Then
                                If Worksheets("TRACK").Range("AK" & x).Value <> vbNullString Then
                                    If Worksheets("TRACK").Range("AL" & x).Value <> vbNullString Then

                        Set JuntaCampos = Union(Worksheets("TRACK").Range("U" & x), Worksheets("TRACK").Range("AJ" & x), Worksheets("TRACK").Range("AK" & x), Worksheets("TRACK").Range("AL" & x), Worksheets("TRACK").Range("AM" & x), Worksheets("TRACK").Range("CR" & x))
                        JuntaCampos.Copy

                        myTargetName.Activate
                        Worksheets("TRACKING_HERMES").Select
                        Worksheets("TRACKING_HERMES").Range("A" & y).Select
                        ActiveCell.PasteSpecial xlPasteValues
                        Worksheets("TRACKING_HERMES").Range("D" & y) = Left(Worksheets("TRACKING_HERMES").Range("D" & y), 49)
                        Worksheets("TRACKING_HERMES").Range("E" & y) = Left(Worksheets("TRACKING_HERMES").Range("E" & y), 39)
                        Worksheets("TRACKING_HERMES").Range("I" & y) = Format(Now, "yyyy-mm-dd HH:mm:ss.000")
                        Worksheets("TRACKING_HERMES").Range("Q" & y) = "1"
                        Worksheets("TRACKING_HERMES").Range("R" & y) = x
                        y = y + 1


                                    End If
                                End If
                            End If
                        End If
                    End If

            '-------Tracking2
                    pedidosT.Activate

                    If IsEmpty(Worksheets("TRACK").Range("AT" & x)) Then
                        If Worksheets("TRACK").Range("U" & x).Value <> vbNullString Then
                            If Worksheets("TRACK").Range("AP" & x).Value <> vbNullString Then
                                If Worksheets("TRACK").Range("AQ" & x).Value <> vbNullString Then
                                    If Worksheets("TRACK").Range("AR" & x).Value <> vbNullString Then

                        Set JuntaCampos = Union(Worksheets("TRACK").Range("U" & x), Worksheets("TRACK").Range("AP" & x), Worksheets("TRACK").Range("AQ" & x), Worksheets("TRACK").Range("AR" & x), Worksheets("TRACK").Range("AS" & x), Worksheets("TRACK").Range("CR" & x))
                        JuntaCampos.Copy

                        myTargetName.Activate
                        Worksheets("TRACKING_HERMES").Select
                        Worksheets("TRACKING_HERMES").Range("A" & y).Select
                        ActiveCell.PasteSpecial xlPasteValues
                        Worksheets("TRACKING_HERMES").Range("D" & y) = Left(Worksheets("TRACKING_HERMES").Range("D" & y), 49)
                        Worksheets("TRACKING_HERMES").Range("E" & y) = Left(Worksheets("TRACKING_HERMES").Range("E" & y), 39)
                        Worksheets("TRACKING_HERMES").Range("I" & y) = Format(Now, "yyyy-mm-dd HH:mm:ss.000")
                        Worksheets("TRACKING_HERMES").Range("Q" & y) = "2"
                        Worksheets("TRACKING_HERMES").Range("R" & y) = x
                        y = y + 1

                                    End If
                                End If
                            End If
                        End If
                    End If

            '-------Tracking3
                    pedidosT.Activate

                    If IsEmpty(Worksheets("TRACK").Range("AZ" & x)) Then
                        If Worksheets("TRACK").Range("U" & x).Value <> vbNullString Then
                            If Worksheets("TRACK").Range("AV" & x).Value <> vbNullString Then
                                If Worksheets("TRACK").Range("AW" & x).Value <> vbNullString Then
                                    If Worksheets("TRACK").Range("AX" & x).Value <> vbNullString Then

                        Set JuntaCampos = Union(Worksheets("TRACK").Range("U" & x), Worksheets("TRACK").Range("AV" & x), Worksheets("TRACK").Range("AW" & x), Worksheets("TRACK").Range("AX" & x), Worksheets("TRACK").Range("AY" & x), Worksheets("TRACK").Range("CR" & x))
                        JuntaCampos.Copy

                        myTargetName.Activate
                        Worksheets("TRACKING_HERMES").Select
                        Worksheets("TRACKING_HERMES").Range("A" & y).Select
                        ActiveCell.PasteSpecial xlPasteValues
                        Worksheets("TRACKING_HERMES").Range("D" & y) = Left(Worksheets("TRACKING_HERMES").Range("D" & y), 49)
                        Worksheets("TRACKING_HERMES").Range("E" & y) = Left(Worksheets("TRACKING_HERMES").Range("E" & y), 39)
                        Worksheets("TRACKING_HERMES").Range("I" & y) = Format(Now, "yyyy-mm-dd HH:mm:ss.000")
                        Worksheets("TRACKING_HERMES").Range("Q" & y) = "3"
                        Worksheets("TRACKING_HERMES").Range("R" & y) = x
                        y = y + 1

                                    End If
                                End If
                            End If
                        End If
                    End If


            '-------Tracking4
                    pedidosT.Activate

                    If IsEmpty(Worksheets("TRACK").Range("BF" & x)) Then
                        If Worksheets("TRACK").Range("U" & x).Value <> vbNullString Then
                            If Worksheets("TRACK").Range("BB" & x).Value <> vbNullString Then
                                If Worksheets("TRACK").Range("BC" & x).Value <> vbNullString Then
                                    If Worksheets("TRACK").Range("BD" & x).Value <> vbNullString Then

                        Set JuntaCampos = Union(Worksheets("TRACK").Range("U" & x), Worksheets("TRACK").Range("BB" & x), Worksheets("TRACK").Range("BC" & x), Worksheets("TRACK").Range("BD" & x), Worksheets("TRACK").Range("BE" & x), Worksheets("TRACK").Range("CR" & x))
                        JuntaCampos.Copy

                        myTargetName.Activate
                        Worksheets("TRACKING_HERMES").Select
                        Worksheets("TRACKING_HERMES").Range("A" & y).Select
                        ActiveCell.PasteSpecial xlPasteValues
                        Worksheets("TRACKING_HERMES").Range("D" & y) = Left(Worksheets("TRACKING_HERMES").Range("D" & y), 49)
                        Worksheets("TRACKING_HERMES").Range("E" & y) = Left(Worksheets("TRACKING_HERMES").Range("E" & y), 39)
                        Worksheets("TRACKING_HERMES").Range("I" & y) = Format(Now, "yyyy-mm-dd HH:mm:ss.000")
                        Worksheets("TRACKING_HERMES").Range("Q" & y) = "4"
                        Worksheets("TRACKING_HERMES").Range("R" & y) = x
                        y = y + 1
                                    End If
                                End If
                            End If
                        End If
                    End If


            '-------Tracking5
                    pedidosT.Activate

                    If IsEmpty(Worksheets("TRACK").Range("BL" & x)) Then
                        If Worksheets("TRACK").Range("U" & x).Value <> vbNullString Then
                            If Worksheets("TRACK").Range("BH" & x).Value <> vbNullString Then
                                If Worksheets("TRACK").Range("BI" & x).Value <> vbNullString Then
                                    If Worksheets("TRACK").Range("BJ" & x).Value <> vbNullString Then

                        Set JuntaCampos = Union(Worksheets("TRACK").Range("U" & x), Worksheets("TRACK").Range("BH" & x), Worksheets("TRACK").Range("BI" & x), Worksheets("TRACK").Range("BJ" & x), Worksheets("TRACK").Range("BK" & x), Worksheets("TRACK").Range("CR" & x))
                        JuntaCampos.Copy

                        myTargetName.Activate
                        Worksheets("TRACKING_HERMES").Select
                        Worksheets("TRACKING_HERMES").Range("A" & y).Select
                        ActiveCell.PasteSpecial xlPasteValues
                        Worksheets("TRACKING_HERMES").Range("D" & y) = Left(Worksheets("TRACKING_HERMES").Range("D" & y), 49)
                        Worksheets("TRACKING_HERMES").Range("E" & y) = Left(Worksheets("TRACKING_HERMES").Range("E" & y), 39)
                        Worksheets("TRACKING_HERMES").Range("I" & y) = Format(Now, "yyyy-mm-dd HH:mm:ss.000")
                        Worksheets("TRACKING_HERMES").Range("Q" & y) = "5"
                        Worksheets("TRACKING_HERMES").Range("R" & y) = x
                        y = y + 1

                                    End If
                                End If
                            End If
                        End If
                    End If


            '-------Tracking6
                    pedidosT.Activate

                    If IsEmpty(Worksheets("TRACK").Range("BR" & x)) Then
                        If Worksheets("TRACK").Range("U" & x).Value <> vbNullString Then
                            If Worksheets("TRACK").Range("BN" & x).Value <> vbNullString Then
                                If Worksheets("TRACK").Range("BO" & x).Value <> vbNullString Then
                                    If Worksheets("TRACK").Range("BP" & x).Value <> vbNullString Then

                        Set JuntaCampos = Union(Worksheets("TRACK").Range("U" & x), Worksheets("TRACK").Range("BN" & x), Worksheets("TRACK").Range("BO" & x), Worksheets("TRACK").Range("BP" & x), Worksheets("TRACK").Range("BQ" & x), Worksheets("TRACK").Range("CR" & x))
                        JuntaCampos.Copy

                        myTargetName.Activate
                        Worksheets("TRACKING_HERMES").Select
                        Worksheets("TRACKING_HERMES").Range("A" & y).Select
                        ActiveCell.PasteSpecial xlPasteValues
                        Worksheets("TRACKING_HERMES").Range("D" & y) = Left(Worksheets("TRACKING_HERMES").Range("D" & y), 49)
                        Worksheets("TRACKING_HERMES").Range("E" & y) = Left(Worksheets("TRACKING_HERMES").Range("E" & y), 39)
                        Worksheets("TRACKING_HERMES").Range("I" & y) = Format(Now, "yyyy-mm-dd HH:mm:ss.000")
                        Worksheets("TRACKING_HERMES").Range("Q" & y) = "6"
                        Worksheets("TRACKING_HERMES").Range("R" & y) = x
                        y = y + 1

                                    End If
                                End If
                            End If
                        End If
                    End If

            '-------Tracking7
                    pedidosT.Activate

                    If IsEmpty(Worksheets("TRACK").Range("BX" & x)) Then
                        If Worksheets("TRACK").Range("U" & x).Value <> vbNullString Then
                            If Worksheets("TRACK").Range("BT" & x).Value <> vbNullString Then
                                If Worksheets("TRACK").Range("BU" & x).Value <> vbNullString Then
                                    If Worksheets("TRACK").Range("BV" & x).Value <> vbNullString Then

                        Set JuntaCampos = Union(Worksheets("TRACK").Range("U" & x), Worksheets("TRACK").Range("BT" & x), Worksheets("TRACK").Range("BU" & x), Worksheets("TRACK").Range("BV" & x), Worksheets("TRACK").Range("BW" & x), Worksheets("TRACK").Range("CR" & x))
                        JuntaCampos.Copy

                        myTargetName.Activate
                        Worksheets("TRACKING_HERMES").Select
                        Worksheets("TRACKING_HERMES").Range("A" & y).Select
                        ActiveCell.PasteSpecial xlPasteValues
                        Worksheets("TRACKING_HERMES").Range("D" & y) = Left(Worksheets("TRACKING_HERMES").Range("D" & y), 49)
                        Worksheets("TRACKING_HERMES").Range("E" & y) = Left(Worksheets("TRACKING_HERMES").Range("E" & y), 39)
                        Worksheets("TRACKING_HERMES").Range("I" & y) = Format(Now, "yyyy-mm-dd HH:mm:ss.000")
                        Worksheets("TRACKING_HERMES").Range("Q" & y) = "7"
                        Worksheets("TRACKING_HERMES").Range("R" & y) = x
                        y = y + 1

                                    End If
                                End If
                            End If
                        End If
                    End If

            '-------Tracking8
                    pedidosT.Activate

                    If IsEmpty(Worksheets("TRACK").Range("CD" & x)) Then
                        If Worksheets("TRACK").Range("U" & x).Value <> vbNullString Then
                            If Worksheets("TRACK").Range("BZ" & x).Value <> vbNullString Then
                                If Worksheets("TRACK").Range("CA" & x).Value <> vbNullString Then
                                    If Worksheets("TRACK").Range("CB" & x).Value <> vbNullString Then

                        Set JuntaCampos = Union(Worksheets("TRACK").Range("U" & x), Worksheets("TRACK").Range("BZ" & x), Worksheets("TRACK").Range("CA" & x), Worksheets("TRACK").Range("CB" & x), Worksheets("TRACK").Range("CC" & x), Worksheets("TRACK").Range("CR" & x))
                        JuntaCampos.Copy

                        myTargetName.Activate
                        Worksheets("TRACKING_HERMES").Select
                        Worksheets("TRACKING_HERMES").Range("A" & y).Select
                        ActiveCell.PasteSpecial xlPasteValues
                        Worksheets("TRACKING_HERMES").Range("D" & y) = Left(Worksheets("TRACKING_HERMES").Range("D" & y), 49)
                        Worksheets("TRACKING_HERMES").Range("E" & y) = Left(Worksheets("TRACKING_HERMES").Range("E" & y), 39)
                        Worksheets("TRACKING_HERMES").Range("I" & y) = Format(Now, "yyyy-mm-dd HH:mm:ss.000")
                        Worksheets("TRACKING_HERMES").Range("Q" & y) = "8"
                        Worksheets("TRACKING_HERMES").Range("R" & y) = x
                        y = y + 1

                                    End If
                                End If
                            End If
                        End If
                    End If


            '-------Tracking9
                    pedidosT.Activate

                    If IsEmpty(Worksheets("TRACK").Range("CJ" & x)) Then
                        If Worksheets("TRACK").Range("U" & x).Value <> vbNullString Then
                            If Worksheets("TRACK").Range("CF" & x).Value <> vbNullString Then
                                If Worksheets("TRACK").Range("CG" & x).Value <> vbNullString Then
                                    If Worksheets("TRACK").Range("CH" & x).Value <> vbNullString Then

                        Set JuntaCampos = Union(Worksheets("TRACK").Range("U" & x), Worksheets("TRACK").Range("CF" & x), Worksheets("TRACK").Range("CG" & x), Worksheets("TRACK").Range("CH" & x), Worksheets("TRACK").Range("CI" & x), Worksheets("TRACK").Range("CR" & x))
                        JuntaCampos.Copy

                        myTargetName.Activate
                        Worksheets("TRACKING_HERMES").Select
                        Worksheets("TRACKING_HERMES").Range("A" & y).Select
                        ActiveCell.PasteSpecial xlPasteValues
                        Worksheets("TRACKING_HERMES").Range("D" & y) = Left(Worksheets("TRACKING_HERMES").Range("D" & y), 49)
                        Worksheets("TRACKING_HERMES").Range("E" & y) = Left(Worksheets("TRACKING_HERMES").Range("E" & y), 39)
                        Worksheets("TRACKING_HERMES").Range("I" & y) = Format(Now, "yyyy-mm-dd HH:mm:ss.000")
                        Worksheets("TRACKING_HERMES").Range("Q" & y) = "9"
                        Worksheets("TRACKING_HERMES").Range("R" & y) = x
                        y = y + 1

                                    End If
                                End If
                            End If
                        End If
                    End If

            '-------Tracking10
                    pedidosT.Activate
                    Application.CutCopyMode = False
                    If IsEmpty(Worksheets("TRACK").Range("CP" & x)) Then
                        If Worksheets("TRACK").Range("U" & x).Value <> vbNullString Then
                            If Worksheets("TRACK").Range("CL" & x).Value <> vbNullString Then
                                If Worksheets("TRACK").Range("CM" & x).Value <> vbNullString Then
                                    If Worksheets("TRACK").Range("CN" & x).Value <> vbNullString Then

                        Set JuntaCampos = Union(Worksheets("TRACK").Range("U" & x), Worksheets("TRACK").Range("CL" & x), Worksheets("TRACK").Range("CM" & x), Worksheets("TRACK").Range("CN" & x), Worksheets("TRACK").Range("CO" & x), Worksheets("TRACK").Range("CR" & x))
                        JuntaCampos.Copy

                        myTargetName.Activate
                        Worksheets("TRACKING_HERMES").Select
                        Worksheets("TRACKING_HERMES").Range("A" & y).Select
                        ActiveCell.PasteSpecial xlPasteValues
                        Worksheets("TRACKING_HERMES").Range("D" & y) = Left(Worksheets("TRACKING_HERMES").Range("D" & y), 49)
                        Worksheets("TRACKING_HERMES").Range("E" & y) = Left(Worksheets("TRACKING_HERMES").Range("E" & y), 39)
                        Worksheets("TRACKING_HERMES").Range("I" & y) = Format(Now, "yyyy-mm-dd HH:mm:ss.000")
                        Worksheets("TRACKING_HERMES").Range("Q" & y) = "10"
                        Worksheets("TRACKING_HERMES").Range("R" & y) = x
                        y = y + 1

                                    End If
                                End If
                            End If
                        End If
                    End If




                'Loop
                Next x


            'close file Pedidos without saving
            pedidosT.Close savechanges:=False


            End Sub
```

The program only stops and give the error "Subscript out of range" whenever i have a Tracking10

Any help or improvement would be very apreciated.

thanks in advance

Comment: Which line is giving you the error?

Comment: It gives no error in any line. But when he find values in ----Tracking10 
 gives the error "subscript out of range"
It does not happen when he finds values in any other tracking, only in Tracking10

Comment: strangely, he copies and paste the values he finds before the error "Subscript out of range". The cells are correct, indexes also, the values are ok in all other trackings, only the part of tracking 10 gives this error.

Comment: SOLVED: The problem was when the loop from tracking10 to tracking1, missed in the begining of tracking1 the code " pedidosT.Activate".
Spent 2 days looking at this and didn't see it :(